# How to use module type in ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import, ejs

I want to import react in ejs it shows cannot use import statement outside module.

`import React from react`

When I execute this ^^^ I get error cannot use import statement outside module.

`const {React} = require("react")`

When I run this ^^^ it gives me error require is not defined...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `script` type as `module` to be able to use `import` statement / `ES Module` :

If you are using node.js, you have to edit your `package.json` and set :

```
{
    "type": "module",
}
```

Else, if you import your js `script` from an `html` balise you have to set (almost the same thing) :

```
<script src="app.js" type="module" ></script>
```

This will enable the use of `import` inside `app.js`